# Document Library in code behind

Tags: development, document-library

I am trying to get the document library from my SharePoint 2010 site.

Let's say, my Document library name is 'Proposals' and Site is 'Http://sok:1234' .

I used the code like,

**`SPDocumentLibrary doclib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["http://sok:1234/Proposals"];`**

Does it look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should use Id or Display name of your library

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sok:1234"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPDocumentLibrary doclib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["Proposals"];
    }
}
```

Comment: That Did the Trick :)